# Create more than one column using apply in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create 6 new columns from my actual data using functions.

If I want just one, I know how to do it.

```
def R1(df):
  O,C,H,L = df['O'], df['C'], df['H'], df['L']
  #
  P1,P4 = H,L
  if O < C: P2,P3 = C,O
  else: P2,P3 = O,C
  #
  D1 = P1-P2
  D2 = P2-P3
  D3 = P3-P4
  #
  try: R1 = D1/D2
  except ZeroDivisionError: R1 = 1
  return R1

df['R1'] = df.apply(R1, axis=1)
```

And obviously I can repeat it six times. But my question is, how can I add 6 columns at the same time if I have the following function.

```
def Rx():
  O,C,H,L = df['O'], df['C'], df['H'], df['L']
  #
  P1,P4 = H,L
  if O < C: P2,P3 = C,O
  else: P2,P3 = O,C
  # 
  D1 = P1-P2
  D2 = P2-P3
  D3 = P3-P4
  #
  R1 = D1/D2
  R2 = D1/D3
  R3 = D2/D1
  R4 = D2/D3
  R5 = D3/D1
  R6 = D3/D2

  return R1,R2,R3,R4,R5,R6
```

I tried options like the following but always fail...

```
df['R1,R2,R3,R4,R5,R6'] = df.apply(Rx, axis=1)
df[['R1,R2,R3,R4,R5,R6']] = df.apply(Rx, axis=1)
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: You need to separate the column names in to separate strings. `df.loc[:, ['R1', 'R2', 'R3', 'R4', 'R5', 'R6']] = df.apply(Rx, axis=1)`

Comment: I did it but appears the following error `ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable`